# Countries list in different languages with same country code

Tags: multilingual, country-codes

For a multi-language application I need to display country lists. These lists must be in different languages but I need to have country codes too so I only save them.

Anyone known an online resource for this?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.freeformatter.com/iso-country-list-html-select.html

Has good resources for non-translated country codes.

If you want something translated, you are unable to do so as there is no guarantee that someone who lives in a country speaks that language.
You could also just copy it off someone else’s website.

PS:
Remember to search google first.

Comment: thanks! been googling but could not find  any good list in the languages I need (for now: English + Swedish)